# How to use regular expression to modify a text file in r and obtain the desired file?

Tags: r, regex, writetofile

I have dataframe like this:

```
Patient_ID=c(10001,10002,10002,10003,10001,10004,10005,10005,10006,10006)
Diagnosis_Codes=c(1,16,5,55,28,1,1,12,14,83)
Diag_Index= c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
df=data.frame(Patient_ID,Diag_Index,Diagnosis_Codes)
df
```

I used the following code to have wide-format data:

```
library(reshape2)
wide_df <- dcast(df, Patient_ID ~ Diag_Index, value.var='Diagnosis_Codes')
wide_df

  Patient_ID  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
1      10001  1 NA NA NA 28 NA NA NA NA NA
2      10002 NA 16  5 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
3      10003 NA NA NA 55 NA NA NA NA NA NA
4      10004 NA NA NA NA NA  1 NA NA NA NA
5      10005 NA NA NA NA NA NA  1 12 NA NA
6      10006 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA 14 83
```

Now I need to convert this dataframe to a text file in which NAs are removed and columns are separated by ,0, except for the first and second column I need only the “comma” as a separator!  The last column would be ,0

The desired text file should look like this:

```
10001,1,0,28,0
10002,16,0,5,0
10003,55,0
10004,1,0
10005,1,0,12,0
10006,14,0,83,0
```

Using the following code, I converted the df to a text file and use ,0, as a separator.

```
write.table(wide_df, file = “raw_file.txt", row.names=FALSE, col.names=FALSE, sep=",0,")
```

Then tried to edit the file by regular expression to omit the NAs and make other required changes but I don’t know much on regular expression and could not get it done yet! Is the regular expression the right method for this problem? or I should do something else? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to go from your long `data.frame` to your desired output.

Here's a possibility:

```
library(data.table)
out <- as.data.table(df)[, sprintf("%s,0", 
  paste(Diagnosis_Codes, collapse = ",0,")), Patient_ID]
out
#    Patient_ID        V1
# 1:      10001  1,0,28,0
# 2:      10002  16,0,5,0
# 3:      10003      55,0
# 4:      10004       1,0
# 5:      10005  1,0,12,0
# 6:      10006 14,0,83,0
fwrite(out, file = "your_file.csv", row.names = FALSE, col.names = FALSE)
```

Comment: @NimaCaiser, No problem. Do consider [accepting the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if it solved your problem.